# how to directly open the doc page of a s4 class?

Tags: r, class, r-s4

Is there a way to directly open the doc page of a s4 class? for example the mle-class:

http://127.0.0.1:16875/library/stats4/html/mle.html

I have tried the followings, none seem to work:

```
?mle-class
?`mle-class`
?"mle-class"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must load the package first.  This does work:

```
library(stats4)
?"mle-class"
```

as does these, also assuming you have done it after loading the package:

```
?`mle-class`

class?mle
```

Comment: Thanks. I confirm that stats4::"mle-class" notation also works. only if I place the cursor in the class string and I press F1 in rstudio!!